# Material design web MDCTab:interacted event not emitting after activateTab

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, material-components, material-components-web

I'm using this

https://material.io/develop/web/components/tabs/tab-bar/

To make a tab bar

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

<div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
    <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
        <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
            <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">

                <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                        <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">title</span>
                        <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Name</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
                        <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                        <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">style</span>
                        <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Tags</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                        <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                        <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">favorite</span>
                        <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Status</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                        <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                        <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">warning</span>
                        <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Restriction</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                        <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                        <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">keyboard_arrow_right</span>
                        <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Other</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                        <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this JS

```
    const tabBar = mdc.tabBar.MDCTabBar.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-tab-bar'));
    tabBar.listen('MDCTab:interacted', function (event) {
        alert(1);
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-tab-bar button')[3].click();
    //tabBar.activateTab(3);
```

Invoking the click works (via code or manually with mouse), and emits the event and alerts "1". However I would rather use the `activateTab` function, but it only makes the tab active, but does not emit the event.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

The `MDCTab:interacted` event is emitted before tab activation which is why it is not triggered when using the `activateTab` method. `MDCTab:interacted` is actually used by the [MDC tab bar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-tab-bar) to know which tab to activate. Depending on what your end goal is, you may be able to get what you need by using the `MDCTabBar:activated` event instead since it will be triggered by the `activateTab` method and provides the index of the activated tab in the event detail data.

```js
const tabBar = mdc.tabBar.MDCTabBar.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-tab-bar'));
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-tab');
tabBar.listen('MDCTabBar:activated', (event) => {
  const tab = tabs[event.detail.index];
  console.log(tab.children[0].children[1].textContent, 'tab activated');
});

tabBar.activateTab(3); // activate "Restriction" tab
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Material Tabs Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
        <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
          <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
            <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">title</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Name</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">style</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Tags</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">favorite</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Status</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">warning</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Restriction</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">keyboard_arrow_right</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Other</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```